# Safely Driving a Brushless Motor

Tags: heat, brushless-dc-motor, high-current, current-limiting, motor-controller

I am currently building a quad-copter out of an Arduino. I decided to make my own ESCs using MOSFETs, EMF sensors, and the Arduino. These are the motors that will be driven: http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/uh_viewitem.asp?idproduct=6247&aff=61689; This is the 11.1v LiPo: http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/uh_viewItem.asp?idProduct=8934&aff=61689; I understand the basic principals of an ESC's operation, but I still have a few questions that I could not find the answers to:

Will I need any form of current and/or voltage limiting components?
Will the motors burn out with 18+ Amps running through?
Will the enamel on the coil windings burn off?

Thanks.

Comment: I've noticed that the rubber on a regular copper wire will burn if it has current flowing for more that a few seconds with this LiPo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have almost the same motor (DT700) sitting on my desk. No current limiting is necessary, it can handle stall currents for a few seconds. After that, the enamel may overheat and burn. Also damage to the magnets by heating above Curie point is possible. For extended periods with heavy load PWM throttling to keep the average current below \$18\,\mathrm{A}\$ is needed.

The maximum sustainable current also depends on cooling. With locked rotor and no air movement even limiting to 18A can lead to overheating after a while.

**Edit:** It is not advisable to start a BLDC with full throttle from dead stop. Something between 10 and 30 percent will work smoother and better.